# Is it possible to group and sum segments/nodes in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

With orders being received back, if an order line is split across two boxes, the company are returning the XML with some of the quantity in one carton, and some in another for the same shoe. This causes us problems because when we send it back to the ERP, it sends for example 4 lines, when there's only 3 lines on the order.

I've looked at this article on grouping but i'm getting so lost! Basically all i want to do is group it by article, so i can sum the quantity and keep it to the same line.

I tried using this tutorial - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1849/Grouping-XML-using-XSLT-2

All I want to do is reproduce that output but with article 261087750000 appearing just once, with quantity 66, rather than twice with 48 and 18.

I tried this in the for-each, but it returns nothing -

```
<xsl:for-each select="//dispatch[generate-id(.) = generate- 
id(key('keyArticle', Carton/CartonDetails/ArticleNumber)[1])]">
<xsl:variable name="lngArticle"><xsl:value-of 
select="Carton/CartonDetails/ArticleNumber" />
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="lstCarton" 
select="//Carton[Carton/CartonDetails/ArticleNumber=$lngArticle]" />
```

Actual XML here -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Dispatches>
 <dispatch>
 <orderNo>4703368395</orderNo>
 <CartonQty>84</CartonQty>
 <Carton>
  <DispDate>20190613</DispDate>
  <CartonDetails>
   <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>                                  
   <ArticleNumber>261087750000</ArticleNumber>
   <Quantity>48</Quantity>
  </CartonDetails>
  <CartonDetails>
   <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
   <ArticleNumber>261135720000</ArticleNumber>
   <Quantity>12</Quantity>
  </CartonDetails>
 </Carton>
 <Carton>
  <BoxNo>0920000075</BoxNo>
  <DispDate>20190613</DispDate>
  <CartonDetails>
   <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
   <ArticleNumber>261087750000</ArticleNumber>
   <Quantity>18</Quantity>
   </CartonDetails>
   <CartonDetails>
   <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
   <ArticleNumber>261087840000</ArticleNumber>
   <Quantity>6</Quantity>
   </CartonDetails>
  </Carton>
</dispatch>
```

Expected result would be -

```
<CartonDetails>
  <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>                                  
  <ArticleNumber>261087750000</ArticleNumber>
  <Quantity>66</Quantity>
</CartonDetails>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider working across multiple templates returning *CartonDetails* with distinct *ArticleNumber*. Then sum the *Quantity* off the key.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="keyArticle" match="CartonDetails" use="ArticleNumber"/>

  <xsl:template match="/Dispatches">
      <Carton>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="dispatch/Carton"/>
      </Carton>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Carton">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="CartonDetails[generate-id() =
                         generate-id(key('keyArticle', ArticleNumber)[1])]"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="CartonDetails">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="LineNumber|ArticleNumber"/>
          <Quantity>
             <xsl:value-of select="sum(key('keyArticle', ArticleNumber)/Quantity)"/>
          </Quantity>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Online Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGcT/1)

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Carton>
   <CartonDetails>
      <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
      <ArticleNumber>261087750000</ArticleNumber>
      <Quantity>66</Quantity>
   </CartonDetails>
   <CartonDetails>
      <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
      <ArticleNumber>261135720000</ArticleNumber>
      <Quantity>12</Quantity>
   </CartonDetails>
   <CartonDetails>
      <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
      <ArticleNumber>261087840000</ArticleNumber>
      <Quantity>6</Quantity>
   </CartonDetails>
</Carton>
```

Comment: Oh interesting, i didnt know that was possible! Thank you. Also side question, in your online demo in xslt fiddle - how did you get the output to appear formatted? it always shows as one line for me.

Comment: That depends on your XSLT processor (and possibly XML viewer) but this stylesheet uses indentation and strips whitespace. In demo you can even change the engine and none of them appear as one line. So it is curious why you get one line.